# Specify Format / set up placeholder for multi-column ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I want to show a placeholder in a `ComboBox` if no values has yet been selected or the previously selected one has been removed / deselected. For single-column `ComboBox`es that works like a charm using `@;"My placeholder"` as the `Format` of the `ComboBox`. So far so good.

The problem starts if my `ComboBox` has more than one column. How can you set the placeholder value for a multi-column `ComboBox`? More general: How can you specify the `Format` for a multi-column `ComboBox`?

Is it for example possible to color the first column green and the second one red? And if it *is* possible, please tell me *how*.
I could not find any specification on how to set the format for multiple columns. Neither on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198058.aspx) nor on [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Specify-how-data-displays-by-using-custom-formatting-a5e5bcde-85da-4c7a-8164-1fe286636668).

P.S.: I do not care if a working solution relies on VBA or if it can achieved just by entering something in the layout or design view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are outgrowing what a ComboBox can easily provide in Access.
First, combo options, and then my real suggestion.

Here are your ComboBox options:

1. Try conditional formatting, and see if you can get the combo's text box to change color if the value is null.
2. You could make a UNION query that appends your placeholder record to the top of your Combo's real recordsource
3. You could try to get your users used to the idea of 'blank' = null, and fix it with training.
4. I have never seen a way to do different combo column colors in Access.

My **REAL** suggestion:

1. Ditch the combo and go with a modal dialog form that pops up for the user. This will let you format everything much more closely to what you want.
2. You can put textboxes on your main form to display the placeholders.
3. The user clicks on the textbox to open your dialog form.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, i do however think that most of them don´t work for me: 1. that would maybe work for colors, but definitely not for placeholders 2. could work, don´t like it, mostly because you can select the placeholder again after choosing a valid value 3. for now i have to go with that :/ 4. me neither. 1. - 3. I already display a dialog with 2-6 combo boxes. Laying textboxes over them might work, but its messy, i will try however try it. Showing even more dialogs would lead to a really uncomfortable UI.

Comment: One thing I would say is 'keep it simple'. I have learned from hard experience that the phrases 'innovative UI' and 'Access' don't go well together. Not to say that you can't do it, but it could well wind up being _much_ more work than you anticipated.

Comment: I am just prototyping a new business model and wanted to know if there is an easy way I am missing - I am very aware of the fact that you cannot build good looking and well performing large scale applications with MS Access :D but is good for prototyping :)